# Django URL alias

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to make some special page with url like /special.html.
Actually it should be just an alias to some page from articles app (for example /articles/2012/03/22/)

Do I need write some magic in urls.conf (and what is that magic?) or it is possible only via web-server rules?

Comment: Do you want that page to ever change? Or will it always be the same target url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do it in your app. You can pass in view arguments in your route.

Something like:

```
url('^/special.html$', articleView,
   {"year": "2012", "month": "03", "id":"1234" }, "article")
```